# Compare the result from trimming textarea with a string

Tags: php

I'm not being able to compare a string from a textarea to a string of mine.
I "divided" the textarea to some lines, each \n =  in this case.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST["code"]); // or use PHP PHP_EOL constant
    if ( !empty($lines) ) {
        foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
            echo trim( $line ).'</br>';
        }
    }
```

Then, I tried to compare the result of that array to a string.

```
if($lines[0] != 'quest'){
        echo "error";
    }else{
        echo "succ";
    }
```

So, what I'm trying to do is check if the first word on my textarea is 'quest', but Im always getting 'error' even when the first word on my textarea is quest.

[image]

[image]

My objective is to get 'succ' if the first line contains quest.

Comment: You are just printing the trimmed result, without changing the original `$lines` content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the trim on your test :

```
if(trim($lines[0]) == 'quest') {
    echo "succ";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```